# How to check if an array has one of the objects in the query an throw all the objects inside of it in Supabase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, supabase, supabase-js

maybe the title of the question is not the best but i don't know how to explain it better in just one line.

So, to have context the best is to see the query that i'm doing in JavaScript for Supabase and its response.

**The data:**

```
[
  {
    title: 'El Hobbit',
    slug: 'el-hobbit-libro-g3kCYxiIII',
    categories: { slug: 'libro', title: 'Libro' },
    tags: [
      { slug: 'epico', title: 'Épico' },
      { slug: 'fantasia', title: 'Fantasía' }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Orgullo y Prejuicio (2005)',
    slug: 'orgullo-y-prejuicio-pelicula-2005-lQoqYD5QuV',
    categories: { slug: 'pelicula', title: 'Película' },
    tags: [ 
      { slug: 'romance', title: 'Romance' },
      { slug: 'romance-historico', title: 'Romance histórico' },      
      { slug: 'drama', title: 'Drama' } 
    ]
  }
]
```

**The query in a function:**

```
async function getReviews() {
  try {
    
    let query = supabase
      .from('reviews')
      .select(
        `
        title,
        slug,
        categories ( title, slug ),
        tags ( title, slug )
      `
      )
      .eq('published', true)

    const { data: reviews } = await query
    return reviews
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching reviews:', error)
  }
}
```

So what I want to make is to show only the records that inside the tags object is the slug, for example, 'romance'. That record should display all of its tags also.

**¿What did I tried?**

Well, I tried to make some kind of filter like so

```
async function getReviews() {
  try {
    // fetch reviews from supabase
    let query = supabase
      .from('reviews')
      .select(
        `
        title,
        slug,
        categories ( title, slug ),
        tags ( title, slug )
      `
      )
      .eq('published', true)
      .in('tags.slug', ['romance'])

    const { data: reviews } = await query
    return reviews
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching reviews:', error)
  }
}
```

Output (notice the tags):

```
[
  {
    title: 'El Hobbit',
    slug: 'el-hobbit-libro-g3kCYxiIII',
    tags: [],
    categories: { slug: 'libro', title: 'Libro' }
  },
  {
    title: 'Orgullo y Prejuicio (2005)',
    slug: 'orgullo-y-prejuicio-pelicula-2005-lQoqYD5QuV',
    tags: [{ slug: 'romance', title: 'Romance' }],
    categories: { slug: 'pelicula', title: 'Película' }
  }
]
```

But what I expected was something like

```
[
  {
    title: 'Orgullo y Prejuicio (2005)',
    slug: 'orgullo-y-prejuicio-pelicula-2005-lQoqYD5QuV',
    categories: { slug: 'pelicula', title: 'Película' },
    tags: [ 
      { slug: 'romance', title: 'Romance' },
      { slug: 'romance-historico', title: 'Romance histórico' },      
      { slug: 'drama', title: 'Drama' } 
    ]
  }
]
```

I know maybe this is a dumb question, but I'm a new with postgres and supabase. Hope you guys can give me a hand. Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code snippet may help you to get all the data that its tags array contains "romance".

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('reviews')
  .select('*')
  .cs('tags:slug', ['romance']);

if (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
} else {
  console.log('Filtered data:', data);
}
```

With the `cs` method you check if the `tags:slug` contains that "romance" exists. I would appreciate help if this did not work or even if you got a different result which is more close to what you want.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but didn't worked because seems that `cs` method do not exist for this Postgres Filter Builder created by Supabase.

Comment: @lgodev You can try `contains` instead of `cs`.